# What’s a word or phrase that means “to reduce ambiguity”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*Specify* is the best I can think of, but it doesn’t by itself
capture the change from ambiguity to less ambiguity.

For example:

> "I spent my entire net worth to ride a ship", said Blake.
>
> "Since when did boats become so expensive?"
>
> Blake realized that he had been misunderstood, so he specified his statement. "It wasn't a boat. It was a *rocket*ship that I paid exorbitant amounts of money to ride."

I’ve tried searching for synonyms of *specify* and *clarify*, but
none of them does the trick.

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable.

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: Clarify seems to mean this: it fits in "He then clarified his statement". What's wrong with it?

Comment: @StuartF Okay, on second thought, "clarify" is probably the way to go.

Comment: Or maybe don't use an "intent of the sentence" word in this case -- it's telling and not showing. I almost prefer something like "he grinned fiercely before announcing ... ".

Comment: I don't think you need a new word.  You can inflect it to form "disambiguate".

Comment: You need context to choose a word. What was his original statement?

Comment: I agree "specify" doesn't work. If you specify a statement you are saying which statement, not specifying what it means.

Comment: "It cost me my entire net worth to ride that ships", Did you write this or are you quoting someone? I would like to answer but I find the sentence as you posted it unidiomatic. Also, why are you making two sentences out of it??

Comment: @Lambie I removed the nonsense about water from the second sentence. Does it make more sense now? I'm just making it up

Comment: Blake, in journalistic writing these sentences usually end with: He said, He added. He explained. But they are one sentence only with quote marks: "It cost me my entire net worth to ride that ship", he later explained, specified is not right here. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"Clarify" works in the example sentence.

> ...so he clarified his statement:

The definition of "clarify" closest to the intended purpose is, ["To free of confusion".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clarify)

But the title asked for a word that meant to reduce ambiguity. "Ambiguity" is like a subset of "confusion". So we need a word that is like a subset of "clarify":

> Disambiguate

> linguistics: [to establish a single semantic or grammatical interpretation for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disambiguate)

It could be used as so:

> ... so he disambiguated his intended meaning of the word *ship*:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the first word I thought of; it's common vocabulary, very obvious in meaning, and is widely used in both written and spoken English.

Answer (score 23):

I think that "elaborated" or "clarified" works best for this specific example, since you're *increasing precision* more than *reducing ambiguity*. (There is a fair amount of overlap between the two, but "ambiguity" seems to suggest that there are multiple incompatible interpretations of the statement, rather than just a lack of detail.) But to answer the more general question, **disambiguate** has the exact meaning you're asking for.

Comment: +1 for mentioning **disambiguate.** That seems to most directly fit OP's need here.

Answer (score 18):

**Disambiguate**

I would think the best fit would be Disambiguate. Literally,

> “to remove the ambiguity from; make unambiguous:”

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disambiguate)

I don’t think that the fact that the word is not widely used is of any relevance. In the worst case your audience will fail to understand and choose not to educate themselves as to its meaning. In the best case it communicates precisely what you intend. Unless your audience is incapable for any reason of either understanding or enlightening themselves as to the meaning of the word, it seems like a reasonable risk to take. When I hear a word I don’t know, I look it up.

Comment: While "disambiguated" is not the appropriate word in OP's situation, you *are* technically correct (the best kind of correct).

Comment: After reading the OP’s question a second time I realized that my answer was probably not what they were looking for, which is why I up-voted the answer @ray gave.

Answer (score 8):

> He then **elucidated**: 'There will be no water involved. It's a
> rocketship that I paid exorbitant amounts of money to ride.'

**elucidate** (v.)

> Essential Meaning of *elucidate*
>
> *Formal*: to make (something that is hard to understand) clear or easy to understand
>
> *The spokesman was asked to *elucidate* [=*clarify, explain*] the government's policies (to/for us).*
>
> *When asked for details, he declined to *elucidate* further.*
>
> *Transitive verb*
>
> To make lucid especially by explanation or analysis
> **elucidate* a text*
>
> *Intransitive verb*
>
> To give a clarifying explanation [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidate)

For me, *clarify* by itself is more to rephrase, re-explain or clear up confusion. *Elucidate* is to provide additional details—a fuller/more detailed account. *The choice of a verb may also depend on his *original statement*, which you didn't provide.*

Comment: seems like "elucidate" is tied with "clarify". I wonder if there's a more specific word that has more to do with the reduction of ambiguity than the reduction of unclarity (if ambiguity is a subset of unclarity, I want a word that targets that subset)

Comment: There is *disambiguate*, but it's more a linguistic term: "To establish a single semantic or grammatical interpretation for // "needed to *disambiguate* the phrase" [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disambiguate)

Comment: I  think you want to remove ambiguity rather than (intentionally) reduce it.

Comment: @DjinTonic Software developer here - we also routinely use "disambiguate" as a term of art.

Comment: Extremely odd is it to use *elucidate* intransitively.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Can you elucidate?

Answer (score 4):

> He then **elaborated** on his statement: 'There will be no water involved. It's a rocketship that I paid exorbitant amounts of money to ride.'

[Dictionary.com 7](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elaborated)

> to add details in writing, speaking, etc.; give additional or fuller treatment (usually followed by on or upon)

Answer (score 3):

Your example sentence suggests **qualify**:

*He then qualified his statement: etc.*

[Collins definition 3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/qualify):

> If you qualify a statement, you make it less strong or less general by
> adding a detail or explanation to it.  *I would qualify that by
> putting it into context.  Boyd qualified his opinion, noting that the
> evidence could be interpreted in other ways.*  Synonyms: restrict,
> limit, reduce, vary

Answer (score 2):

I voted for "qualified", he qualified his statement (to provide supporting information).

But literally disambiguated (disambiguation/disambiguation), although this does not *reduce* ambiguity, it *eliminates* ambiguity. This is now in common usage as this is the term used by Wikipedia.

Most of the answers here focus on words that are used to disambiguate.

"to be specific".   (specify one from many).

"narrow it down".   (this is a reducing expression).

"in particular".    (one).

"specifically".     (one).

"notably".          (one example).

"reduces to".       (one or more, but a refined selection).

and other qualify/filter/selection answers already given.

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to say without further context, but I believe the word you are looking for is ***qualified*** . . .

> **qualify**, *v.*
> **II.** To modify or moderate in some respect.
> **8. a.** *transitive*. To modify (a statement, opinion, etc.) by the addition of some limitation or reservation; to make less strong or
> positive. Occasionally *intransitive*.
>   <sub>Source: [Oxford
> English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Imagined context:

> He said, “My rocketship is the first eco-rocketship ever.”
>
> He then **qualified** his statement: “There will be no water involved.
> It’s a rocketship that I paid exorbitant amounts of money to ride.”

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you had already proposed this one.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is **particularise**.

> *particularise* [verb] [formal] [and -*ize*]
>
> If you particularise something that you have been talking about in a
> general way, you give details or specific examples of it. [formal]
>
> - *Mr Johnson particularizes the general points he wants to make.*

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/particularize)]

> *particularize* [verb] [and -*ise*]: to go into details ...
>
> - *He said he had been treated rudely, then went on to particularize.*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/particularize)]

But the expression

- '[He then] **went into details** [about ....]'

is perhaps the most idiomatic phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'illuminate'? It can be a precise synonym of 'clarify, or 'elucidate'.

Answer (score 0):

In French the verb ***préciser*** would be right, I think.

***Clarify*** is the verb most often used in politics reporting in English.

***Disambiguate*** is better where ambiguity exists but it is seldom used in education (apart from IT education) or in the media and this might make its meaning less well understood.

Answer (score 0):

What is, sharpen?

2.
improve
brush up
polish up
better
enhance
hone
refine
fine-tune

Oxford Languages

Comment: Welcome!  Note, you don't have to use the Jeopardy format here.  Plain sentences are okay.  (Best to include a link to the definition you provide.)

Answer (score 0):

Explain:

> To give the reason for or cause of.

--[Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explain)

> "That ship cost me my entire net worth to ride." He later ***explained*** "There was no water involved. It was a rocketship that I paid exorbitant amounts of money to ride."